# Where are DNS servers deployed

Tags: dns

This may be a silly question. But I have googled around and haven't found a satisfying answer on this. 
I know a DNS server is the translator between domain name and IP address. But where are DNS servers deployed/located? In our personal computers, or some other places with isolated machines?

Comment: Your computer's OS might have a local cache of previous responses to DNS queries it has made. Then there is DNS provided by your network router, if you have one.  And then DNS provided by your ISP that gives you Internet access. And then DNS provided by the Internet backbone that the ISP is connected to. Ultimately leading up to the root servers that provide DNS for the TLDs (`.com`, `.net`, `.org`, etc). DNS has many layers to it, and many caches along the chain.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is also muddled and confusing.  In the generic case there is _perhaps_ a cache in the stub resolver, and then one in your recursive resolver.  There's never "many".

Comment: this is a reasonable intro to DNS - https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/

Answer (score -2):

This is a big question so worth googling around.  In a nutshell it depends on what you need to resolve.  DNS resolving internet sites in the big wide world are at eg network connection providers such as BT or large tech firms eg Yahoo / Google.  Local IP addresses are resolved through a local DNS possibly in your Firm or on your router at home.  Between the two there is a concept of delegated authority - so if as a local DNS I have resolved an address oncess once it will provide it as a non-authoritative answer next time it is asked - this helps DNS scale.

So the briefest answer may be external facing authoritative resolution happens with the big internet connectivity providers, they in turn talk to distributed local DNS which serve up internal IP address resolution and non-authoritative answers for external sites if they have seen the site before.  The result is effectively millions of DNS.

You can see which you are hitting by running something like nslookup www.google.co.uk on a command line.  The first IP returned is the DNS your machine is using.

Comment: notwithstanding the question is completely off-topic for this site, this answer is very muddled and is IMHO more likely to confuse than inform.

Comment: Thank you, Rich! More clear now! I was trying to upvote. But my reputation is not enough to make it count.